# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when running with dalvikvm

Tags: android, exception, dalvik

I'm trying to run a JAR file I built using the following command line (from adb shell):

```
dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/MyJar.jar MyJar.main.Main
```

My Main class has only a single method `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Connect to local db
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
```

When I run the command line it looks like the `main` function runs but then I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: native_get_int
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get_int(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.getInt(SystemProperties.java:74)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1846)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
    at MyJar.main.Main.main(Main.java:146)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My guess is that I need to load some kind of library to resolve this link error but I have no clue which library it is (this seems like a basic thing that probably should have been loaded by dalvikvm...).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `app_process` instead of `dalvikvm`.

[Vogar](http://code.google.com/p/vogar/) makes this kind of thing very easy. Check out the latest vogar from their SVN page, build it with ant, and then run this on your Linux desktop

```
~/Projects/vogar/bin/vogar --mode app_process ~/myapp/src/com/me/Main.java
```

Vogar will build your `.java`, create a `.dex` file, use `adb` to copy that to your device, and then execute VM on the device for you. We use it to develop Dalvik.

Comment: Well, It doesn't do exactly what I was looking for. What I'm trying to do is execute a jar file that has my Main class in it from the device shell.

Comment: Use vogar --classpath and specify the main class name? If you run vogar with the --verbose flag, you'll see the command line args it passes to app_process to launch the process on the device. You can run app_process manually using similar args.